# Typescript class can't access attributes from object

Tags: typescript

```
export class Person {
    name: string;
    age: string;
    details: {
      occupation: string;
      height: string;
      gender: string;
    };
}
```

This is an class I have defined in person.ts.

In another file, I am trying to assign a values to all attributes in a new person object. I can access `name` and `age` but I cannot access any attributes in the details object, in the setData() method because the details object is undefined. The code looks like this.

```
import { Person} from '../Classes/person';

export class AnotherClass{

  private person1: Person;

  constructor() {
    this.person1= new Person();
  }

  private setData(){
    this.person1.details.occupation = "doctor";
  }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `this.person1.details["occupation"] = "doctor";`

Comment: Please don't spam tags. This is not angularjs related, or even angular for that matter.

Answer (score 2):

When you are creating a new instance make sure details object get initialize. So in the constructor, set up the structure.

```
export class Person {
    name: string;
    age: string;
    details: {
        occupation: string;
        height: string;
        gender: string;
    };

    constructor() {
        this.details = {
            occupation: null,
            height: null,
            gender: null,
        };
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your typescript class is really just defining the expected shape of the object. You currently aren't providing your properties any default values which is why this is occurring. There are a few ways you can deal with this.

You could update your class to:

```
export class Person {
    name: string;
    age: string;
    details: {
      occupation: string;
      height: string;
      gender: string;
    } = {
      occupation: '',
      height: '',
      gender: ''
    };
}
```

or:

```
export class Person {
    name: string;
    age: string;
    details: {
      occupation?: string;
      height?: string;
      gender?: string;
    } = {};
}
```

This second declaration says that a person will have a details object. The details object has three optional properties and the default value for this object is an empty object.

The problem you are experiencing is that JavaScript's default value is `undefined`. In Typescript, you are saying that you expect the details property to be an object with occupation, height and gender properties. If you create a Person object and try to assign something else to it, the Typescript compiler will complain. ***But***, Typescript doesn't create a default for you for that object. The default is just `undefined` if not otherwise specified. Now when you create a new instance of the Person class, the default currently being assigned to the details property is `undefined`. Then when you are trying to assign a value to a property on `undefined`, the runtime is unhappy.

Both examples above providing a default value for the details object, removing the issue you are having. The difference between them is the default values being assigned to each property of the default object. The first will have an empty string assigned to each property and the second one will have an object with out those properties.

With the first example, you have to provide an object with empty strings for each property as you are declaring in Typescript that each property is required. By adding the `?` in the second example, you are declaring that each property isn't required.

The default object won't have those properties, but in JavaScript when you try to assign a value to a property that doesn't exist yet on the object, JavaScript will create the property on that object and assign the value to it.

Or you could so something that is suggested in the other answers and assign an object to the details property.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you explain how the second block of code works? Does it mean the attributes are optional and if none is provided then set details to an empty object?

Comment: @GeorgeP.Burdell I tried to add more detail, please let me know specifically what still isn't clear if you have further questions.

Answer (score 1):

You just declared the field `details` on person, you did not initialize it to an object, this means `details` will be undefiend and when you try to set a field of default you will get an error. You should create a new object for details in `setData`

```
export class AnotherClass{

  private person1: Person;

  constructor() {
    this.person1= new Person();
  }

  private setData(){
    this.person1.details = {
       occupation: "doctor", 
       height: 10,
       gender: 'female'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the details as an object

```
private setData(){
    this.person1.details = {
       occupation: "doctor", 
    }
  }
```